# java can't concat to end of string

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I'm trying to concat ".png" to the end of a String variable "text." Every method I try ends up replacing the entire string with ".png", however.

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/censored/file.csv"));
        //file has "test,test1,test2,test3" from an excel file

        sc.useDelimiter(",");
        sc.useDelimiter("\n");

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String text = sc.next();

            String pathname = "C:/Users/censored/" + text;
            System.out.println(pathname); //prints "C:/Users/censored/test"
            pathname += ".png";
            System.out.println(pathname); //prints ".png" only
        }
```

I feel like it has to be something with the scanner/sc.next(), as I can get the correct result if I define text to be a string literal. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Maybe `pathname` includes a `\r`? Is `pathname.length()` what you expect?

Comment: Did you not ask this same question yesterday?

Comment: @nomadmaker I didn’t include enough code to replicate it before

Comment: Then you should have edited yesterday's question rather than create a new identical one.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the `useDelimiter()` method, only the "\n" is being used

Try this:

```
sc.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

There was either a newline or a carriage return somewhere in the string, removing all `\n` and `\r` solved it.